# Which word would fit better?

Tags: word-choice

I have to complete a text and there isn’t any given words:

> Her husband .... disliked the painting that he refused to pay for it

I was thinking of Perhaps or Probably since we can deduce from the previous sentence of the clause that the statement is uncertain.

Comment: @Clare -  ***so*** fits, and is what I thought of as well.  *probably* and *perhaps* would be ungrammatical in my book.

Comment: The question is unclear without  context.

Comment: *So* was the first word that came to my mind too.

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  No references?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to express that her husband disliked it in such a way that he refused it, then **So** is the adverb that fits perfectly there.

**That he refused it** is an *subordinate adverbial clause* that implies a result from something, it is almost always used with the adverbs "**so**" and the determiner "**such**":

> He talked to me *in such a rude way* that I didn't want to see him ever again.
>
> I liked the meal *so much* that I would always go there to eat.

**Such** is normally used because **So** can't be used as an adjective phrase:

*He talked to me in a so rude way* - **wrong**

that's where **such** fits.

Answer (score 0):

Clare is right to suggest ‘so’.  The sentence involves what can be called a ‘consecutive clause’.  It starts with a clause that includes the word ‘so’ or ‘such’  and an adjective or adverb, which together express the degree or extent of some quality.  Then there is a second clause, introduced by the word ‘that’, which states the **consequence**.  Thus:

1. The pot was boiling **so** fast **that** it filled the kitchen with steam.

2 The shelf is **so** high **that** you will need a ladder to reach it.

Your sentence is slightly tricky because it has the word ‘so’ on its own, without any adjective or adverb.  Another way of putting it would have been:  “Her husband disliked the painting **so much** that he refused to pay for it.”.

There is a little mystery about sentences of this type:  which of the two clauses is the main clause and which is the subordinate clause.?  Neither stands comfortably on its own, as main clauses usually do.  In Latin or ancient Greek, it is the ‘that’ clause that is treated as grammatically subordinate.

According to the sense, I want to say that the ‘that’ clause is the main clause, because it is the main *point* of the sentence:  the ‘so’ clause merely explains it and so must (in its sense) be subordinate.  This wretched husband refused to buy the painting because he hated it ..so much!

So are they two equal main clauses joined by a sort of consecutive conjunction?  He both hated the picture and (as a result) refused to pay for it.

Or perhaps we have a sentence made up of two subordinate clause bound together by a consecutive conjunction?

I cannot see any strong reason for preferring any of these possibilities, though the last is perhaps idiosyncratic.

Answer (score -1):

As Jim pointed out *so* is a word that fits well here.

Grammar considerations aside, *perhaps* and *probably* do not even fit semantically.

*that he* implies the word you are looking for is the reason he failed to pay for the painting. Perhaps and probably are too unassured.

He *so* disliked the painting, he refused to pay for it, fits because he disliked the painting *so* much -  and this intense dislike was the reason he refused to pay for it.